# Error in Signed xml document using FirmaXadesNet

Tags: c#, digital-signature, signature, xml-signature, xades4j

i have this problem:

Im using the DLL FirmaXadesNet to make a digital signature of an xml invoice, 
the signature looks good at first and no errors are show in Visual Studio 2017,

After create the signature node in the xml file, i move it to another place of the xml.

this file is send to a post service that validate it, but the validation is done in java using xades4j, and is showing an validation error:

"com.indra.mmdd.signature.exceptions.ValidateException: xades4j.verification.ReferenceValueException: Reference '' cannot be validated"

I dont know what can be the reason for this error... Any Help?

My code:

XadesService xadesService = new XadesService();

```
        SignatureParameters parametros = new SignatureParameters();

        // Política de firma de factura-e 3.1
        parametros.SignaturePolicyInfo = new SignaturePolicyInfo();
        parametros.SignaturePolicyInfo.PolicyIdentifier = "https://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/politicafirma_v1_0.pdf";
        parametros.SignaturePolicyInfo.PolicyHash = "Ohixl6upD6av8N7pEvDABhEL6hM=";
        parametros.SignaturePolicyInfo.PolicyDigestAlgorithm = FirmaXadesNet.Crypto.DigestMethod.SHA1;
        parametros.ElementIdToSign = "";
        parametros.ExternalContentUri = "";

        parametros.SignaturePackaging = SignaturePackaging.ENVELOPED;
        parametros.SignerRole = new FirmaXadesNet.Signature.Parameters.SignerRole();
        parametros.SignerRole.ClaimedRoles.Add("supplier");
        parametros.DigestMethod = FirmaXadesNet.Crypto.DigestMethod.SHA1;
        parametros.SignatureMethod = SignatureMethod.RSAwithSHA1;
        parametros.SigningDate = SigningDate;

        MemoryStream xmlStream = new MemoryStream();
        Stream SignedXmlStream = new MemoryStream();
        documentoxml.Save(xmlStream);

        xmlStream.Flush();//Adjust this if you want read your data 
        xmlStream.Position = 0;

        using (parametros.Signer = new Signer(certificate))
        {
            var docFirmado = xadesService.Sign(xmlStream, parametros);
            docFirmado.Save(SignedXmlStream);
            docFirmado.Save("c:\\temp\\tst.xml");
            SignedXmlStream.Flush();
            SignedXmlStream.Position = 0;
            documentoxml = XDocument.Load(SignedXmlStream);
        }
```

The Signature created:

```
<ds:Signature xmlns:ds="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#" Id="Signature-befa877d-93fe-4e08-90ea-a4ef88909281">
  <ds:SignedInfo>
    <ds:CanonicalizationMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/TR/2001/REC-xml-c14n-20010315" />
    <ds:SignatureMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#rsa-sha1" />
    <ds:Reference Id="Reference-9cf35641-377a-45cf-870c-5a271096d051" URI="">
      <ds:Transforms>
        <ds:Transform Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#enveloped-signature" />
      </ds:Transforms>
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <ds:DigestValue>mxAO1rCV4xSQJ344nmjmcMEyAks=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
    <ds:Reference Id="ReferenceKeyInfo" URI="#KeyInfoId-Signature-befa877d-93fe-4e08-90ea-a4ef88909281">
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <ds:DigestValue>IC1iMTiQbgwaX5bK9NAUdcny09E=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
    <ds:Reference Type="http://uri.etsi.org/01903#SignedProperties" URI="#SignedProperties-Signature-befa877d-93fe-4e08-90ea-a4ef88909281">
      <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
      <ds:DigestValue>/sJWqf4CxhbVAPj0nJxcoNeLh/Q=</ds:DigestValue>
    </ds:Reference>
  </ds:SignedInfo>
  <ds:SignatureValue Id="SignatureValue-befa877d-93fe-4e08-90ea-a4ef88909281">o121CWPg2cIQkw8lyySSM/CDiC/tsHs0197mjht1XFvdQAXhaBdvoXxjFlVGAGulEBf0o9q/+pJ5PCCuL5RzPvNc3ThUDKyVrExbGJhk7qV0HTtbYiOuSNt53G70aENhx48Npo2wijSYDnGg8urOuW+c7k5QN/wse4r4pyFP4mn9VxqrsyrD33/h2cSKbVBRz8TodsGeCPWSAAVfNKKmD1vlglizwk2BoZ0dpqialy4VjR8D0ZyHISZxNhWPRFIKh0dxul0XGkgp2YUpWR6qm/0mZZsSSG4QgW5DfgBfcHD0JAiSeL1AT4EkgI5Q+psmD2eXRW2x81/sXGtfw3sK1w==</ds:SignatureValue>
  <ds:KeyInfo Id="KeyInfoId-Signature-befa877d-93fe-4e08-90ea-a4ef88909281">
    <ds:X509Data>
      <ds:X509Certificate>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</ds:X509Certificate>
    </ds:X509Data>
    <ds:KeyValue>
      <ds:RSAKeyValue>
        <ds:Modulus>sfnoInlr7Dil0R4ePQSmz4eflgkPLnCcDjK9LLz4o5Rk1BrVDlaAr7fLZ2W9C3290kVbbnEwufzYBiLSZ40lOlQSHPoHHpIkYxfcY2CTqZeolwhMtz9T68GKdKOAZAuWIntkK3V9H0rdELcvlk/BNgGKOQEDGEpWKUoxgHOxwVsEWKMtWABRQLwRt99/WLplUg0voILIede1BdDB93kg2ey5HWRORnqw/IoqW8oL2p0dRwdqu3LwRHLl8iOjqvNaCbcTWt4fyLiuPovYDTopwCiOZIqsva7gAESlqBGIh9/zBPHMrOcdd6wq+mr5k2kWpGJ/ivyjkBMZjHp0x8AxcQ==</ds:Modulus>
        <ds:Exponent>AQAB</ds:Exponent>
      </ds:RSAKeyValue>
    </ds:KeyValue>
  </ds:KeyInfo>
  <ds:Object Id="XadesObjectId-f05adc2c-eba5-4612-b76c-9588208b98f5">
    <xades:QualifyingProperties xmlns:xades="http://uri.etsi.org/01903/v1.3.2#" Id="QualifyingProperties-9160de7a-7c5a-4961-9364-412b9dc4f483" Target="#Signature-befa877d-93fe-4e08-90ea-a4ef88909281">
      <xades:SignedProperties Id="SignedProperties-Signature-befa877d-93fe-4e08-90ea-a4ef88909281">
        <xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
          <xades:SigningTime>2017-10-10T19:58:13-05:00</xades:SigningTime>
          <xades:SigningCertificate>
            <xades:Cert>
              <xades:CertDigest>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>vffAvJLY1zLdUh2p2mN6Er80eTc=</ds:DigestValue>
              </xades:CertDigest>
              <xades:IssuerSerial>
                <ds:X509IssuerName>CN=AC SUB CERTICAMARA, O=CERTICAMARA S.A, OU=NIT 830084433-7, C=CO, S=DISTRITO CAPITAL, L=BOGOTA, STREET=www.certicamara.com</ds:X509IssuerName>
                <ds:X509SerialNumber>161545504811122332844050240895274705943</ds:X509SerialNumber>
              </xades:IssuerSerial>
            </xades:Cert>
          </xades:SigningCertificate>
          <xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
            <xades:SignaturePolicyId>
              <xades:SigPolicyId>
                <xades:Identifier>https://www.dian.gov.co/contratos/facturaelectronica/politicafirma_v1_0.pdf</xades:Identifier>
                <xades:Description />
              </xades:SigPolicyId>
              <xades:SigPolicyHash>
                <ds:DigestMethod Algorithm="http://www.w3.org/2000/09/xmldsig#sha1" />
                <ds:DigestValue>Ohixl6upD6av8N7pEvDABhEL6hM=</ds:DigestValue>
              </xades:SigPolicyHash>
            </xades:SignaturePolicyId>
          </xades:SignaturePolicyIdentifier>
          <xades:SignerRole>
            <xades:ClaimedRoles>
              <xades:ClaimedRole>supplier</xades:ClaimedRole>
            </xades:ClaimedRoles>
          </xades:SignerRole>
        </xades:SignedSignatureProperties>
        <xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
          <xades:DataObjectFormat ObjectReference="#Reference-9cf35641-377a-45cf-870c-5a271096d051">
            <xades:MimeType>text/xml</xades:MimeType>
            <xades:Encoding>UTF-8</xades:Encoding>
          </xades:DataObjectFormat>
        </xades:SignedDataObjectProperties>
      </xades:SignedProperties>
    </xades:QualifyingProperties>
  </ds:Object>
</ds:Signature>
```

Comment: Empty URI on "ds:Reference" means that you sign the whole XML resource that contains the signature. If you are moving the signature, that might be the source of the problem, because the validation will consider a different XML content. Could this be the problem?

Comment: I will see if that is the problem, in that case, i must let the signature as a child at the end of the document???

Comment: I guess so. You could also try to create it in a different way, e.g. not using an empty URI but a specific reference. I don't know FirmaXadesNet...

Comment: Ok i check the process signing de xml, the problem is that i have to sign the document but the sign must be in an explicit node in the xml and with the FirmaXadesNet the sign is the last node, because the dll adds the node as the last child in the xml... Any idea?

Comment: Can't you send the whole XML file to the validation server? Since you're signing something, it would help to also send what you signed :P Keep in mind that an "enveloped" signature is one that is contained withing the resource it signs.